# Why does ejabberd stop modules before closing c2s process?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I add some modules following the gen_mod behaviour in ejabberd to realize my private service, and add some hooks in these modules. This works well most time.

```
  ejabberd_hooks:add(unset_presence_hook, Host,
    ?MODULE, unset_presence_hook, 10),
```

But When I call ejabberdctl stop, ejabberd excecute the following code, I found that
`gen_mod:stop_modules()` was done before `broadcast_c2s_shutdown()`, 
some hooks in ejabberd_c2s e.g. "unset presence hook" , cannot be excecuted because of my modules had been closed.

```
prep_stop(State) ->
    ejabberd_listener:stop_listeners(),
    gen_mod:stop_modules(),
    ejabberd_admin:stop(),
    broadcast_c2s_shutdown(),
    timer:sleep(5000),
    State.
```

I would like to know Why does ejabberd stop modules before closing c2s process,
or what is the purpose of this design?

Comment: Probably broadcast_c2s_shutdown was just added at the end of fun. See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/7cbda8badbc0323ae7e52400c3abc70a093b8bbf

Comment: @Lol4t0, Sorry, but i cannot understand what this commit means, and it caused a little problem to me.